# Stack Overflow index page points to videos

Tags: discussion, architecture

It was expected to see an error page when `index.html` was appended to https://stackoverflow.com/:

[image]

But when I change the URL to https://stackoverflow.com/index.php, it is redirecting to **YouTube**

> Why is that redirecting to a YouTube page rather an error page?

Browser: Google Chrome

**Edit 1 :**

All communities' `index.php` pages redirect to a YouTube video.

Stack Exchange shows a valid error page:

[image]

*Why is such redirection added?*

Comment: this is not a bug, this is by design

Comment: :) saw that first time..thought to ask in meta

Comment: It's a joke. Why wouldn't it be added?

Comment: @jonrsharpe we would love to see these videos on every error page  :)

Comment: However, still waiting for YouTube embed feature in [aviation.se] :)

Comment: @utility that's punishment for you thinking you can write websites like these with PHP.

Comment: :) @Glorfindel how come that be a punishment ! dont joke

Comment: Is this legal? I assume you have permission from Google/YouTube? Otherwise why not just tarpit them?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

That is by design.

[Nick Craver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13249/nick-craver), one of the [Site Reliability Engineers/Developer](https://stackoverflow.com/company/team#Engineering) (Chief Maintenance Mode), tweeted about this a while a go: [Just deployed Stack Overflow. Have fun, bots:](https://twitter.com/nick_craver/status/720062942960623616)

He basically added Redirect responses for the most common attempted pages often used by hackers and script kiddies. For the redirect target he decided to choose a video that keeps them occupied for a while ...

For search-ability matters here are the routes:

- `admin.php`
- `admin/login.php`
- `administrator/index.php`
- `ajaxproxy/proxy.php`
- `bitrix/admin/index.php`
- `magmi/web/magmi.php`
- `index.php`
- `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`
- `wp-admin/post-new.php`
- `wp-admin/options-link.php`
- `wp-admin/includes/themes.php`
- `wp-login.php`
- `xmlrpc.php`

Comment: thats a great idea..but redirecting to non SO site is not a good idea though

Comment: Most important thing is to get them away from Stack Overflow as quickly as possible without consuming resources. Redirecting them to YouTube who can handle the load easy is the best option. I don't see why hackers should have a great user experience.

Comment: thats a good reason @rene .. thank you for taking note of my question :)

Comment: Just to add to rene's answer, you can get the code below: https://gist.github.com/NickCraver/c9458f2e007e9df2bdf03f8a02af1d13

Comment: This is a terrible idea.

Comment: It is a great idea