# index.php not working

Tags: bug

Some videos of the [`index.php`](https://stackoverflow.com/index.php) [redirect](https://twitter.com/nick_craver/status/720062942960623616) are broken.
This is a critical issue.

Broken links:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sagg08DrO5U
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KMFOVSWn0mI
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ER97mPHhgtM
- Maybe [more](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Cf4tGbVWQAETAYM.jpg), who knows how much this has spread?

I know I don't need to state the importance of this.

Send help.

Comment: Sorry, missed that you said the videos themselves were broken. I half think we should suggest replacements but I worry that would get too ridiculous.

Comment: It seems the 3 links listed above are the only ones which are broken. That's 30 hours of lost content we have to replace...

Comment: [WTF](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O-dNDXUt1fg)? Honeypot April Fools Day Edition? :D Thanks, I have to think about the seriosity of the Stack Overflow developers now ;)

Comment: We need a [tag:high-priority] tag for these sort of critical issues.

Comment: Why did I never know about that!

Comment: Well if @NickCraver wasn't so busy writing [long blog posts about silly network things](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2017/05/22/https-on-stack-overflow/) he'd have the time to devote to fixing the important stuff like this.

Comment: I thought I was hallucinating when I saw this question title under hot meta posts.

Comment: Video links from the screenshot: http://youtu.be/wbby9coDRCk http://youtu.be/nb2evY0kmPQ http://youtu.be/eh7lp9umG2I http://youtu.be/z9Uz1icjwrM http://youtu.be/Sagg08DrO5U http://youtu.be/09m0B8RRiEE http://youtu.be/jI-kpVh6e1U http://youtu.be/jScuYd3_xdQ http://youtu.be/S5PvBzDlZGs http://youtu.be/9UZbGgXvCCA http://youtu.be/O-dNDXUt1fg http://youtu.be/MJ5JEhDy8nE http://youtu.be/VnnWp_akOrE http://youtu.be/jwGfwbsF4c4 http://youtu.be/8ZcmTl_1ER8 http://youtu.be/q44qwyHlMfk http://youtu.be/ozPPw153c_4 http://youtu.be/KMFOVSWn0mI http://youtu.be/clU0Sh9ngmY http://youtu.be/sCNrK-n68CM

Comment: OK. Can someone explain this to a web-noob? Do bots go to index.php? Not all bots are bad, right (e.g. google, duckduckgo,...)? Why would a bot get "stuck" with listening to Gandalf partying for 10 hours? Do they have that much attention span?

Comment: @AnderBiguri See here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/330161/1663001

Comment: Its a crime this was closed as off topic.  And that 10 hours of Brodyquest isn't being served up by index.php https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YWa-rWSsoZA

Answer (score 29):

> That's 30 hours of lost content we have to replace...

Actually not. I have found duplicates of the content:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Ep_aPSrwYI
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4on4s3OoD6E
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jr9R9NT9lk8

The last one was a little tricky, but nothing that was impossible because of [archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20170201172816/https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ER97mPHhgtM).

We should mark the old ones as duplicates, and protect them by a 10k users. This is the highest priority for now.

Comment: @TinyGiant thanks for removing the nonsensical statement. Much better now :)

Comment: (after reading the revisions for said statement) First of all Christian, how dare you.

Comment: The way Jim Carey moves his head tho... I believe his skeleton is not like mine.