# YouTube video for anti-bot redirect is down

Tags: bug

For those who are unfamiliar,

*[Stack Overflow index page points to videos](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330160/stack-overflow-index-page-points-to-videos)*

I tried this this morning for laughs, and it directed me to this video:

https://youtu.be/KMFOVSWn0mI

Which has been taken down due to copyright grounds :/

Not really a bug, just a heads-up.

Comment: The hunt for a new video begins. - [I'll just leave this here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9DFkxRj-pxY)

Comment: @Ihazkode give me teh codez?

Comment: Related: [index.php not working](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349957/index-php-not-working). *Send help!*

Comment: 10 hours of Brodyquest. Slightly nsfw, unless you like cashews.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YWa-rWSsoZA

Comment: It must be said that my vote goes to the one and only Mr Astley - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ.

Comment: Candidate fitting replacement: [Trolololo](https://youtu.be/o1eHKf-dMwo).

Comment: *hands over a plastic-wrapped code snippet* - @cat

Comment: index.php redirected me to [this](https://youtu.be/nb2evY0kmpQ)

Comment: This vulnerability report should be eligible for the [bug bounty program](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/297423/271659).

Comment: @ConnorGurney You can even have [10 hours of Mr Astley](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=66tQR7koR_Q)

Comment: Well, damn, that's what I call love @Tiny Giant.

Comment: @Connor Never gonna give it up.

Comment: Never gonna let you down.